# Windows 10 IoT core+rasperry pi+camera sensor?

Tags: windows-iot-core-10

Does Windows 10 IoT core supports rasperry pi camera sensor?If So,which libraries are there in C# to code camera module?

Answer (score 2):

Windows IoT officially supports several types of usb cameras, find a completed list from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/hardwarecompatlist#Cameras.

If you're developing under UWP framework, which has built-in support for various cameras, follow the tutorial from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/camera.

Microsoft also provides sample projects for camera development, find it in https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

**No**, Windows 10 IoT Core does NOT support the CSI module (Camera Serial Interface) of a Raspberry Pi.

@Jackie posted already a link with the supported cameras. In my experiences other may work but it is not guaranteed.